# randomly generate the number within a specified range but condition is that two numbers are not same

Tags: random

I want to generate the random number within a specified range but condition is that generated two number is not same.
I use following code for generating the random number.

```
 A=randi(100,1,39)
```

which will give me a set of 39 number between 1 to 100. it also generate the same number. i.e in following set of number 44 comes two times.

A =

Columns 1 through 25

```
78    49    44    45    31    51    52    82    80    65    38    82    54    36    94    88    56    63    59    21    31    48    24    85    20
```

Columns 26 through 39

```
23    18    23    **44**    32    93    44    19    91    98    **44**    12    26    41
```

kindly suggest me to generate a random number but any of generated number is not repeat in set of generated number.

Comment: _"random number but any of generated number is not repeat in set of generated number"_ - that's not random. There is a chance (a small one, but still) that you get the same number 39 times. Try doing some research. You actually seem to want to generate a list of numbers within the range you want to support, then shuffle that list, then take an amount of numbers off that list.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @ Byte Commander Matlab

Answer (score 0):

`random.sample` gives you a random sample set, which doesn't contain duplicates.

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> sample(range(1, 100), 39)
[7, 80, 81, 6, 79, 83, 62, 54, 89, 55, 34, 63, 31, 95, 38, 48, 46, 37, 26, 1, 2, 60, 86, 98, 13, 75, 85, 67, 10, 70, 72, 47, 20, 61, 76, 74, 15, 25, 30]
```

Comment: Correct in case the OP uses Python 3. For Python 2 you should use `xrange` instead of `range` for better performance and memory consumption.